# Jquery trying to remove dynamically made elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery to dynamically add elements to my form and then remove them if necessary, I can do this when there is only one form being added, however my next form allows the user to add an ingredient and it adds a quantity element with it, I cant work out how to remove both the elements with a button. I have created a JSfiddle would be great if something could help.

http://jsfiddle.net/w5PKZ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var addDiv2 = $('#addIngredient');
    var i = $('#addIngredient p').size() + 1;

    $('#addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
        $('<p> <input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="ingredient[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Ingredient" /> </p>').appendTo(addDiv2);
        $('<p> <input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="quantity[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" /><a href="#" class="remNew2">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv2);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click','.remNew2', function () {
        if (i > 3) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i - 2;
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: First, to do this without problems: you can't use ID more then once (you are creating 2 inputs with the same ID).
Second, add wrappers for new fields, so you can delete added fields by this wrapper (in wrapper you can have ingedient, quelity and remove button) - it will be easier to program. And also clearer.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328883/jquery-removing-a-cloned-element/20329178#20329178
Similar thing as you want to achieve.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w5PKZ/11/ - this is not full answer, cos I don't have time now. But you can see here, how it can be done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5PKZ/6/)

Add the dynamic elements in a single paragraph `<p>` instead of 3 different paragraphs. This way you can keep your event handler AS IT IS.

```
$('#addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
    $('<p> <input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="ingredient[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Ingredient" /><input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="quantity[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" /><a href=#" class="remNew2"> Remove </a> </p> ').appendTo(addDiv2);
    i++;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $(this).parent().prevAll(':lt(2)').remove().end().remove();
```

Your selection gets only the element "remove", you must also select the newly added using .prevAll()

**Note:** id's must be unique

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5PKZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UQbKL/)</kbd>

```
$(document).on('click', '.remNew2', function () {
    if (i > 1) {
        $(this).parents('p').prev().remove();
        $(this).parents('p').prev().remove();
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('#addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        var newDiv = $("<div></div>");
        $('<p> <input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="ingredient[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Ingredient" /> </p>').appendTo(newDiv);
        $('<p> <input id="step_' + i + '" size="40" name="quantity[]' + '" type=text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" />').appendTo(newDiv);
        $('<p> <a href=#" class="remNew2"> Remove </a> </p>').appendTo(newDiv).click(function(){
        newDiv.remove();
        });
        addDiv2.append(newDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w5PKZ/10/

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to build a basic tag and then individually add the arguments rather than passing in a long html string.

You can add the remove event handler directly to the individual anchors and pass in references to the elements you want removing if you do it all in the same scope as you create the elements:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4CVuL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var addDiv2 = $('#addIngredient');
    var i = $('#addIngredient p').size() + 1;

    $('#addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
        var p1 = $( '<p />' )
                        .appendTo(addDiv2),
            p2 = $( '<p />' )
                        .appendTo(addDiv2),
            p3 = $( '<p />' )
                        .appendTo(addDiv2),
            ingredient = $( '<input />' )
                        .attr( 'id', 'ingredient_' + i )
                        .attr( 'size', '40' )
                        .attr( 'name', 'ingredient[]' )
                        .attr( 'type', 'text' )
                        .attr( 'placeholder', 'Ingredient' )
                        .val( $( '#ingredient_1' ).val() )
                        .appendTo( p1 ),
            quantity =  $( '<input />' )
                        .attr( 'id', 'quantity_' + i )
                        .attr( 'size', '40' )
                        .attr( 'name', 'quantity[]' )
                        .attr( 'type', 'text' )
                        .attr( 'placeholder', 'Quantity' )
                        .val( $( '#quantity_1' ).val() )
                        .appendTo( p2 ),
            a = $( '<a />' )
                        .attr( 'href', '#' )
                        .text( 'Remove' )
                        .appendTo( p3 )
                        .on( 'click', function(e) {
                            p1.remove();
                            p2.remove();
                            p3.remove();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // DO NOT DECREMENT i - you may get duplicate IDs
                        } );
        i++;
        return false;
    });
});
```

You could also just add all the elements to `p1` rather than creating multiple paragraphs (and it would be better semantically if you used `div` elements rather than `p` elements).